# IOS - How to retrieve images and strings from parse and set UIImageview and UIlabel in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, parse-platform, uicollectionview

Ok so Im using storyboards and Trying to add String data that goes with the images

the images are in the same row with the name of the picture in parse 
I got the image and was able to put it on a UICollectionView im just having trouble connecting the name that goes with it in the same cell
.
how do i get a different name that goes with the image for each cell

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self queryParseMethod];
self.userCollection.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
}

- (void)queryParseMethod {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"imageandtitle"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        imagefilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [userCollection reloadData];
    }
 }];
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [imagefilesArray count];
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
userCCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"userCard" forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
    {
        self.affiliates = objects;

        for(NSDictionary *affiliate in self.affiliates) {

            //cell.Name.text = affiliate[@"Name"];

            NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:affiliate[@"Name"], nil];
            for (NSString *name in array) {
                PFObject *imageObject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                cell.Name.text = name;

            }
        }
    }
}];
PFObject *imageObject = [imagefilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PFFile *imageFile = [imageObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
PFObject *nameofUser = [imageObject objectForKey:@"Name"];
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        cell.userPI.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
 }];
return cell;
}
```

I Am currently only getting one name and if i try to uncomment the other cell.text i still get one name but in all cells.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: There's some nice Apple sample code for UITableView that you can easily adapt. Now remember that cells are very temporary objects. If you do things in the background while your user is scrolling, this will end in disaster. Look at Apple's sample code.

Comment: If you don't know how to find this sample code, ask a question.

Comment: i tried i couldn't exactly get it

Comment: if you can provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys the answer was really simple i just had to remove the for loop and query since i already queried as a method then type

```
cell.Name.text = [imageObject objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

thank you for your time.